# During Gradle expand/copy, How do I include secondary files from a DIFFERENT FOLDER into a master file?

Tags: gradle, groovy, include, copy

This is a follow up from: [How/Can I include secondary files into a file during gradle's expand/copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42567945/how-can-i-include-secondary-files-into-a-file-during-gradles-expand-copy)

If in a folder, 'templates',  I have 2 files, Master.xml and Child.xml, and in Master.xml I have this line:

```
${new File("$DESTDIR/templates/Child.xml").getText()}
```

The Child.xml has its tokens processed and is included in the resultant Master.xml.  This works wonderfully.

However, if I place Child.xml in a DIFFERENT folder, even a subfolder:

```
${new File("$DESTDIR/templates/include/Child.xml").getText()}
```

Then processResources fails, complaining it cannot find Child.

Summary:  ${....getText()} works for files in the same folder, but fails for different folders.

Any suggestions on how to overcome this?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Only by pure luck did I find a resolution.  The underlying issue is the order in which folders and files are picked up.

Initially I figured I could control the folders by using a perceived sort order of "_1_ProcessFirst", "_2_ProcessSecond", etc.  But that implied ordering was completely ignored.   I eventually landed upon using A_... and Z_..., etc, and that worked perfectly.

I don't know if that's the proper solution, or if using 'include' is preferred.  I  had no luck in making any 'include' attempt work.

Are underscores ignored, or treated specially?  In theory, _1_XXX should have worked.

I hope this helps someone else down the line.